# Is asking specifics about Theatres on topic on Travel?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question regarding the internals of a West End Theatre, a comment on my [Related Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257790/site-for-discussing-west-end-theatres) suggested Travel.SE as a potential resource, but I can't decide if it would be on topic or not, so I thought I'd ask here first.

So: Would a question regarding what is "wrong" with a certain block of cheaper seats in a particular theatre be on topic here at Travel?

Comment: Most of the time there's a limited view, like a fixture is in the way or something else blocking the view.  Sometimes it's a bad rake, but not often. Sometimes it's noise from the street or bar, but also not often.

Comment: @GayotFow Yeah - In this case they're billed as "side view of the stage", but there's some seats that are 25% of the price of the seat right next to them.  I was wondering how a "side view" seat can go from being worth full price to 25% in the space of a seat :)  This isn't the place for it though!

Comment: The box seats at the Palace Theatre (Cambridge Circus) are a special hell unto their own. Obstructed view, obstructed sound... total crap.  Nobody but tourists will even sit there.  But they are standard price.  I think it's on topic for TSE, but the bulk of regulars on TSE do not generally associate the two activities.

Comment: @GayotFow Nice.  In case people haven't clicked through to my Meta.SE question - someone there recommended [SeatPlan](http://www.seatplan.com) for this specific scenario.  It helped me decide!

Comment: @JamesThorpe The difference of one seat can be enough to see past a pillar (or other obstruction) without it blocking your view and it blocking your view of part of the stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your main concern is about theatre seating rather than travelling to the theatre then I would say that **no the question wouldn't be on-topic on Travel SE**.